# Form transition over image

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

I am basically trying to recreate the the Directions, Availability and Resident Login section about half way down this website http://www.livewestvillage.com/. I haven't had the chance to learn css all to well so if somebody could show me an example or a site that's good to learn this type of thing from I would appreciate it.

I've just been swamped at work so I don't really get as much time for personal projects like this anymore.

Comment: what is your issue in the link?

Comment: I want to have a form transition over an image when you mousover an image like how they have it half way down.

Comment: Where is the minimal working example of your issue with the code?

Comment: I believe Fiido93 actually hit the nail on the head with his example. Only issue I noticed with it was that if you start typing in one of the boxes and move your mouse away and then back again it kind of freaks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example how to achieve those effect. I already comment the css, hoping that you will learn something.

**HTML**

```
<h1>
Hover Me!!
</h1>

<div class="box">

<div class="widget-image">
<img src="http://www.livewestvillage.com/media_library/2014/58c310ba3db6a855.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="widget-form">
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}


input {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 6px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.widget-form {
    padding: 43px 0px;
    width: 426px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    z-index: 100;
}

//set the position of the widget
.widget-image{
  width: 426px;
}

//when the mouse enter the div will scroll up
.widget-image:hover + .widget-form {
      top: 0;
} 

//maintain the div position
.widget-form:hover, .widget-form:focus ,  .widget-form :active {
  top: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9o2hksft/)

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. Only issue I noticed was that if you start typing and move your mouse away then move it back it somewhat breaks the form/image transition a little.

Answer (score 1):

Create a form tag with an id `reg`

Absolutely positioned the form tag in the div with class `slider`

Apply a transform scale property to 0x0

Apply a hover property to slider container to make the form show

[click here for pen](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/ZeVdKx)

**Edit:Another approach**

Create a form tag with an id `reg`

Absolutely positioned the form tag in the div with class `slider`

position the element top:100% to push it down and hide it

apply a `:hover` pseudo on the slider to show the form

Here is another example  [click here for pen](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/RpEzLP)

Comment: I was able to get something similar working earlier, my biggest problem was to get the form to hide when it slides off of the image how they had it. The only problem with what you have is that when the form slides down it covers up other items on the page.

Comment: answer updated.. you can hide it by using top:100% which pushes it below the parent container and hide it

Comment: great almost there

Comment: I honestly don't know what I would do without help from everyone like you guys. It sucks coming home after a long day and getting stuck on things as little as this. I appreciate the help